# Generate/inject systemd unit files from script/program

Tags: shell, systemd

How can I inject/generate systemd unit (service) files from a script or program, for example a Bash-script or Python-script?

Should I use a library (in e.g. Python) (which library?) or should I create raw unit files in the filesystem and then use the `systemctl` command? Is a `systemctl daemon-reload` necessary? Maybe the systemd C-API supports this?

Is it a good pattern/practice? Should I develop an application that is started by systemd which then starts the commands, this means: Should I outsource the starting-procedure to my application or should I left that at systemd?

Comment: What is the typical use case for that?